# Webapp start and stop listener using jax-rs

Tags: jax-rs

I am using jax-rs for restful service. And I am trying to find out how I can use a contextlistener for webapp ? I am specifically using jax-rs 2.0 . Any suggestions on how to go about it , would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Can you give more details about what you want to do with the Context Listener ? It's not really connected to JAX-RS..

Comment: @XavierCoulon . I have a service which works on syncing neo4j databases with any updates made to mysql. I have written it as a singlethreaded scheduled threadpool. I need to start this threadpool when the tomcat starts, inorder to sync the updates. and I need to end the service when the tomcat stops, and end it gracefully. I tried using servletcontextlisteners but they do give me a linkage error when I use servlet.jar with jax-rs jar's. So I am trying to find out how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what linkage problem you have with servlet.jar. It should actually be in your classpath already, since JAX-RS uses it, too.

Also, if you use a framework such as Hibernate (or another JPA implementation for your MySQL database access), you may want to rely on the events that they trigger after insert/update/delete operations: see https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/manual/en-US/html/events.html for example.
Just my 2c.